# keras 2 - fit_generator on Jupyter notebook broken?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

---

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5818

---

I've updated to keras v2 yesterday.

I adapted all my code from version 1 to the new API, following all the warnings I encountered.

However I'm having some very strange problems with `fit_generator` method of `Model`.

Using this toy example, wich worked totally fine in version 1:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

gen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_batches = gen.flow_from_directory("D:/GitHub/Kaggle/redux/train/")

inp = Input(shape=(256,256,3))
l1 = Flatten()(inp)
out = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(l1)

model = Model(inp, out)

model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01))

model.fit_generator(train_batches, train_batches.samples // train_batches.batch_size)
```

The output in jupyter notebook is quite strange, printing a unknown symbol until the notebook crashes:

```
Epoch 1/1
 23/718 [..............................] - ETA: 522s - loss: 8.4146
```

Running the code from the terminal don't print those strange symbols.

Comment: Just a stupid question, in the second parameter of fit_generator you use float division (/), what happen if you use integer division (//) ?

Comment: Maybe is a stupid question., but I don't know the answer and S.O is a place to post your questions. By the way using integer division yield the same result. Manually passing an Integer yield the same result.

Comment: "Stupid" was about my question, not your's. I was just trying to eliminate a possible typo or minor detail.

Anyway, from what I get with my own network, after the move to keras 2 the counter seems to display the number of batch, not the number of samples.

Comment: I missunderstood the stupid. Sorry.  I didn't notice that the number been displayed is the number of batch. That was one thing I was not noticing. Thanks!. I'm still having the strange symbol print bug when running on jupyter notebooks.

Comment: It seems to be some control chars used by the progress bar, I don't know enough about jupyter here …

Answer (score 0):

Does the Jupyter notebook give you an error message? You can try setting verbose=0 in fit_generator. That will prevent the progress bar from being displayed.